# How to undo a "git update-index --assume-unchanged" on a directory. "--no-assume-unchanged" does not work

Tags: git, git-index

I have used

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged [directory name]
```

and expected that

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged [directory name]
```

would undo that command.  However, it says "Ignoring path [directory name]" and the directly continues to be ignored.

I have also tried

```
git update-index --really-refresh --no-assume-unchanged [directory name]
```

but that did not work either.

I have tried doing

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged [file]
```

for each file inside the directory, but the directory is still being ignored.

I am using git version 1.8.4.mysysgit.0

Is there another way to make git stop ignoring a directory?

Comment: Maybe try `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged dirname/*` (because Git only tracks files, not directories)

Comment: @knittl I tried your suggestion and it is unable to do it because there is a sub directory that has spaces in the name.  At least I am assuming that is why.  It says, "fatal: Unable to mark file [sub directory name with spaces]"

Comment: @knittl I tried your suggestion on the sub directory and it seems to have worked.  Thanks.  I must have missed individual files when I was doing it file by file.